# Volley and Fragments - how to wait for a request to end

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I'm doing a request for a JSONArray using Volley. At the same time I'm creating Fragments in my Activity, one of them being a ListFragment. I have to populate the list with the Array that I get from that request. But the onCreateView() in Fragments is called BEFORE I get the array in the result, resulting in an empty array showing in a ListView.

What can I do to make this synchronous or to wait a little or to make the list redraw itself when the array is populated?

I've tried Volley Future Request but I don't know how to use them with custom Listeners in my Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView should have some sort of data adapter, probably an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), associated with it (you need to create this, it isn't automatic).

If you're using an `ArrayAdapter`, in the listener for your Volley request, `add()`/`addAll()` your results into the adapter.  The adapter will automatically cause the ListView to refresh.

If you've created your own adapter type that doesn't derive from `ArrayAdapter`, you'll have to handle the notification of changes manually.  That's what [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) does -- just call it after making your changes in the adapter, and it will refresh the view.

Comment: I do have a Custom Adapter extending BaseAdapter, so it should be notyfing? Still nothing.

Comment: no, BaseAdapter doesn't automatically notify, I think.  You need to manually call `notifyDataSetChanged()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Volley gives you handle to callback listeners on your request.

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener() {
 @Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
 }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
 }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Copied the above code from [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) . Maybe you could update the list view onResponse() callback.

Comment: I'm trying this now. Got it to work by calling a new adapter each time the view is created but for a big list it's completely unefficient. I'll try shifting it into response so it can be changed only when updated by request.